# Future<UserData> returns a Future<UserData> instead of a UserData variable

Tags: firebase, flutter, asynchronous, firebase-authentication, future

I have a widget that uses a Future - async that returns a UserData variable, but for some reason, I'm getting a Future  variable instead.

a line of code from a widget Build:

```
dynamic user = Auth.signIn(_email, _password);
```

Auth Class:

```
Future<UserData> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    try{
      UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password
      );
      print('signed in!');
      return _createUserFromFirebase(userCredential.user.uid, null);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        print('No user found for that email.');
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

`return Future.value(_createUserFromFirebase(userCredential.user.uid, null);`

instead of

`return _createUserFromFirebase(userCredential.user.uid, null);`

Answer (score 0):

Async cannot be used without it being in a function with await. You can't randomly retrieve an asynchronous variable randomly in the script without loading it asynchronously, because the future might not have the data ready to be used.

If you need the future variable's future value to be in a widget try using the [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget. This will make it so that the user data is loaded asynchronously and a place holder of your choice can be shown before it loads. This would allow you to use the UserData type in your widget.

Or you can get the user by having the button have an async variable that sets a variable in the widget from null to the UserData after signing in.

Comment: The problem is that I need to supply the future method the email and the password, and I get them inside the same widget (field text)

Comment: If you need the Future for the field text widget, then try wrapping the field text widget in a future builder.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a new future method inside the widget class that saves the user in a variable:

```
  Future<void> getUserData(String email, String password) async{
    _user = await _auth.signIn(email, password);
    print('user: $_user');
  }
```